# Couldn't decrypt the repo, please make sure you enter the right password

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-deliver

I can't run the "Fastlane release", because it shows the error "Couldn't decrypt the repo, please make sure you enter the right password!".
I'm sure that the entered password is correct. I tried to remove all profiles and certificates manually but it didn't work.

```
    [13:03:58]: Enter the passphrase that should be used to encrypt/decrypt your certificates
[13:03:58]: This passphrase is specific per repository and will be stored in your local keychain
[13:03:58]: Make sure to remember the password, as you'll need it when you run match on a different machine
[13:03:58]: Passphrase for Match storage: ********
[13:04:10]: Type passphrase again: ********
[13:04:16]: wrong final block length
[13:04:16]: Couldn't decrypt the repo, please make sure you enter the right password!
keychain: "/Users/mohsen/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
version: 512
class: "inet"
attributes:
    0x00000007 <blob>="match_https://bitbucket.org/******"
    0x00000008 <blob>=<NULL>
    "acct"<blob>=<NULL>
    "atyp"<blob>="dflt"
    "cdat"<timedate>=0x32303230303332343038333431355A00  "20200324083415Z\000"
    "crtr"<uint32>=<NULL>
    "cusi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "desc"<blob>=<NULL>
    "icmt"<blob>=<NULL>
    "invi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "mdat"<timedate>=0x32303230303332343038333431355A00  "20200324083415Z\000"
    "nega"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "path"<blob>=<NULL>
    "port"<uint32>=0x00000000 
    "prot"<blob>=<NULL>
    "ptcl"<uint32>=0x00000000 
    "scrp"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "sdmn"<blob>=<NULL>
    "srvr"<blob>="match_https://bitbucket.org/****"
    "type"<uint32>=<NULL>
password has been deleted.
```

Comment: You have to start with an empty repo and then run fastlane match to push the certificates

Comment: You also have to run fastlane certificates, maybe nuke if you're desperate

Comment: I face the same issue, did you fix it.@Mohsen mokhtari